# Focus outline not displayed on a div with mask-image CSS rule in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, accessibility

I have several divs in my code that have the `mask-image` and `-webkit-mask-image` css rule applied to them. These divs are functioning as UI slider elements, so I want keyboard users to be able to tab between them and use the arrow keys to increment or decrement them.

This seems to work fine in Chrome, however I noticed that in Firefox the mask image rule seems to override the default behavior of creating an outline around elements when they come into focus with the tab button.

Here is a simplification of the situation:

```css
.masked {
  mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba( 0, 0, 1),transparent);
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), transparent);
}
```

```html
<div tabindex=0>
 I'm just a normal div! 
</div>
<div class='masked' tabindex=0>
 I have a mask image css rule. 
</div>
<div tabindex=0>
 I'm just a normal div!  
</div>
```

I noticed that when switching the `<div>` to be a `<button>` element the focus works fine in Firefox, however I'm not sure if it makes sense to use button elements for a slider functionality. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In the fiddle, is there supposed to be an outline for the masked div when clicked on/focused? Oh nvm, there is an outline on chrome but it's very thin comparing to the others

Comment: Yeah, specifically when you press tab (I have tabindex=0 on the divs). As you saw in chrome the mask-imaged div's outline is effected by the mask-image rule, but in Firefox it doesn't seem to show up at all

Comment: That's probably how FF implemented it, to work around it, just wrap your masked item and put the tabindex on the parent so the mask does not mask the parent `<div tabindex=0><div class='masked'> I have a mask image css rule. </div></div>` works on my mac FF

Comment: Thanks @Huangism that works perfectly, think I was just being lazy!

Comment: Given that in Chrome the default outline is thicker and it's barely visible with this mask, I decided against filing it as a bug against Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably how FF implemented it, to work around it, just wrap your masked item and put the tabindex on the parent so the mask does not mask the parent <`div tabindex=0><div class='masked'> I have a mask image css rule. </div></div>` works on my mac FF

– Huangism Aug 15 at 19:21

Answer (score 1):

A bit late for an answer, I realize, but in case it helps someone else.

It seems that, in Firefox, masks are applied to all components of the element, including the outline that thus may become hidden (it is sometimes possible to catch glimpses of the outline through some masks).

A cleaner solution than the accepted answer — imo — that does not involve tweaking the HTML in an un-semantic way by adding a `<div>` wrapper would be setting the mask on the `::after` pseudo-element (or `::before`; in many cases it does not seem to matter much) while keeping the outline on the main element, like so:

```css
.masked {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
.masked::after {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    mask-size: 100%;
    content: ' ';
    mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), transparent);
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), transparent);
}
```

This is the approach that I use for custom-styling form widgets with SVG images. It also has the added benefit of preserving the main element's ability to adjust its color properties on state change (e.g. changing the perceived background color on hover).